# Request to merge tags: [php-fpm] and [php5-fpm]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, merge

I noticed recently that some FPM questions are tagged [php5-fpm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php5-fpm) and others [php-fpm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/php-fpm). I'm not sure there's any useful distinction here, should probably be merged.

Answer (score 4):

FPM has been bundled with PHP 5.3.3 and on wards, so having two different tags does not make any sense until php6 is released. I still doubt that the FPM functionality will heavily change.